# Need to change the normal checkbox tick as bootstrap checkbox tick

Tags: html, css, checkbox, bootstrap-4

I have 2 checkbox and one of the checkbox is created using Bootstrap and one is normal. I want to show the normal checkbox as like bootstrap tick box.

[image]

Below is my code:

```css
.custom-checkbox-input {
     position: relative;
     z-index: 1;
     display: block;
     min-height: 1.5rem;
     padding-left: 1.5rem;
}
 .custom-checkbox-input .form-check-input {
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
}
 .custom-checkbox-input .form-check-input::after {
     content: '';
     display: inline-block;
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
     border: solid 1px grey;
     border-radius: 2px;
}
 .custom-checkbox-input .form-check-input:checked::after {
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
     border: solid 1px red;
     content: '✔';
     background-color: red;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
}
 .custom-checkbox-input .form-check-input .custom-color-grey::after {
     background-color: grey;
}
 .custom-checkbox-input .form-check-input .custom-color-white::after {
     background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="custom-checkbox-input">
        <input class="form-check-input custom-color-white" type="checkbox">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want two checkboxes to be consistent with the tick mark, my suggestion to use a font awesome icon.

```css
.custom-checkbox-input {
     position: relative;
     z-index: 1;
     display: block;
     min-height: 1.5rem;
     padding-left: 1.5rem;
}
 .custom-checkbox-input .form-check-input {
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
}
 .custom-checkbox-input .form-check-input::after {
     content: '';
     display: inline-block;
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
     border: solid 1px grey;
     border-radius: 2px;
}
 .custom-checkbox-input .form-check-input:checked::after {
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
     border: solid 1px red;
     content: '\f00c';
     font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; 
     font-weight:900;
     background-color: red;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
     font-size:13px;
     position:relative;
     top:-2px;
     
}
 .custom-checkbox-input .form-check-input .custom-color-grey::after {
     background-color: grey;
}
 .custom-checkbox-input .form-check-input .custom-color-white::after {
     background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="custom-checkbox-input">
        <input class="form-check-input custom-color-white" type="checkbox">
    </div>
```